# open text file from several file when clicked on button in android

Tags: android, android-studio

i want create a book in android stodio
for example: i want when i click on first_season button open text1.txt file and when click on second_season button open text2.txt file and the rest as I said.
and i dont want make a activity for each page.
and i want use switch case for get button id and based on that id open the text file.
i just want to know how use switch case for create this application.
i use this code for open txt file:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nitish);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    txtView.setText(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
```

consider names of my buttons are 
season1, season2, season3, season4
and name of my text files are 
txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4
thank for helping

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you mean?

```
Map<Int, String> lookupTable = new HashMap<>();

lookupTable.put(R.id.season1, "txt1");
lookupTable.put(R.id.season2, "txt2");
// etc


for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : lookupTable.entrySet()) {  
     findViewById(entry.getKey()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               txtView.setText(readBookPageFromFile(entry.getValue());
          }

})
```

}

Where `readBookPageFromFile` is your above code with the filename as a parameter.